# Weird functionality using tkinter scale with iter(loader).next()

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi All I have `noise_scale` function which gets the current value of the scale (scale has 3 levels - 0, 10, 20) and then performs some test by feeding a randomly sampled image and label. The `iter(testloader).next()` is used to sample a random image and corresponding label. If I use the `iter(testloader).next()` outside the function and print the `(image,label)` pair, it prints just one image and label, however if I use the `iter(testloader).next()` inside the function and prints the `(image,label)` pair, I get three images and their respective labels. I can't seem to figure out what's causing that. Below is my sample code for review:

```
test= data_utils.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(test_set),torch.from_numpy(label_set))
loader = data_utils.DataLoader(test,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
image, label = iter(loader).next()

print(image)  # this prints only one image
print(label)  # this prints the corresponding label

def noise_scale(scale_value=0):
    
    image, label = iter(loader).next()
    print(image)  # this prints three images 
    print(label)  # this prints three labels of images above
    
    if (scale.get()) == 0:
        for i in range(1):
            do_something()
 
    elif (scale.get()) == 10:
        for i in range(1):
            do_something()
    
    elif (scale.get()) == 20:
        for i in range(1):
            do_something()
  
## Scale ##
var3 = StringVar()
scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var3, from_=0, to=20, tickinterval=10, orient='horizontal', resolution=10, length=200, command=noise_scale)
```

Comment: The `command=` function of a Scale is going to get called every time the slider moves to a distinct position, not just once at the end.

Comment: @jasonharper, Yes I get what you mean but with my issue even at a specific position without moving the slider, the ```image, label = iter(loader).next()``` inside the function prints three images. I am not sure if it's from the ```if``` and ```elif``` statements.